# Find/Replace automation in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, automation

I have a great number of text replacements to make in a set of documents in InDesign. They always follow the same formula: Change "this text" to "that text." I've been manually selecting "this text", pasting it into the Find box, then selecting "that text" and pasting it into the Replace box. This is laborious.

Is there a way to feed InDesign these instructions to automate the process? Is there a way to paste the whole sentence into the Find/Replace panel and have the correct information appear in Find and Replace?

Answer (score 9):

Indesign comes with a script called `findchangebylist.jsx`. It does exactly what you want, but it's pretty tedious to use. So tedious, that many people have created scripts for this same task. I would recommend checking some of these out:

- [Find Change By Queries](http://www.kasyan.ho.com.ua/find_change_by_queries.html)

  - My personal favorite. Easy to use.
- [Multi-Find/Change 2.0 ( Indesign and Incopy )](http://automatication.com/index.php?id=22)

  - Extension
  - An older version exists for cs4-cs6
- Grep query manager and runner:

  - [GREP query runner](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/grep_query_runner.html)
  - [GREP query
    manager](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/grep_query_manager.html)
  - [All of Kahrel's GREP utilities](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/grep_matters.html)
- [Batch Find And Replace](https://github.com/fabiantheblind/batch-find-and-replace)
- [XStrings](http://www.kerntiff.co.uk/free-stuff/xchange-strings-xstrings)

Comment: So thanks to Joonas, I've mostly found my solution. XStrings does 95% of what I'm looking for, and with a few tweaks I think I can get it to 100%. Since XStrings creates a text file, which you can then just paste in find/change requests, it works great as a batch solution for non-repetitive, one-time changes. The other solutions mentioned seem geared towards queries you'd want to do theoretically more than once. Thanks again!